# Adding two linked list ends in Infinite Loop

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem [2. Add Two Numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/):

> You are given two **non-empty** linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in **reverse order**, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

My code is ending up in an infinite loop:

```
private static Node addTwoNumbers(Node l1, Node l2) {
    if (l1 == null && l2 == null)
        return l1;
    if (l1 == null) {
        l2.next = addTwoNumbers(l2, l1);
        return l2;
    }
    if (l2 == null) {
        if (l1.data > 9) {
            if (l1.next != null) {
                l1.next.data = l1.next.data + 1;
            } else
                l1.next = new addLinkedList().new Node(1);

            l1.data = (l1.data) % 10;
        }
        l1.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2);
        return l1;

    }

    if (l1.data + l2.data > 9) {
        l1.data = (l1.data + l2.data) % 10;
        if (l1.next != null) {
            l1.next.data = l1.next.data + 1;
        } else
            l1.next = new addLinkedList().new Node(1);

    } else {
        l1.data = l1.data + l2.data;

    }
    l1.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next);
    return l1;

}
```

**Input:** `L1=0->null` `L2=5->9->null`

**Expected output:** `5->9>null`

**My Output:** `5->9->9->9->...`  It goes on like this.

If I replace the 5<sup>th</sup> line by

```
l2.next = addTwoNumbers(l2.next, l1);
```

...then I'm getting the required output, but I still wanted to know why the below code ends in infinite loop.

Comment: l2.next points to the NEXT node. for example, l1 is null, l2 is now 9. if you dont move pointer to the next in line for l2, when it calls addTwoNumbers(), it returns the current value of 9, and keeps recursing + returning 9. It is not able to end.

Comment: Can you link to the original code challenge? Are you sure that it is possible that any of the `data` are greater than 9?

Comment: @trincot - link to the problem - https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
    if (l1 == null) {
        l2.next = addTwoNumbers(l2, l1);
        return l2;
    }
```

The *idea* behind this case is that you swap `l1` and `l2` so that you can deal with the single `null` case without code repetition. That is good, but it is not implemented correctly.

`addTwoNumbers(l2, l1)` -- which is `addTwoNumbers(l2, null)` in this case -- will return `l2`. But then this return value is assigned to `l2.next`, i.e. it performs `l2.next = l2`. That is a cycle! The original `l2.next` referenced the next node, but now the reference to that next node is lost, and instead we have a list with a loop in it.

It is then not *your* code that gets into an infinite loop, but the code that calls your function and then *verifies* the resulting list by iterating it. It is *that* code that will get into an infinite loop.

You propose yourself a valid correction:

```
        l2.next = addTwoNumbers(l2.next, l1);
        return l2;
```

You might also consider just swapping without stepping to the next node:

```
        return addTwoNumbers(l2, l1);
```

#### Other remarks

1. You have:

   ```
   l1.next = new addLinkedList().new Node(1);
   ```

   But that should probably just be:

   ```
   l1.next = new Node(1);
   ```
2. You still have some code repetition. You could avoid that by introducing the `add` variable as done below:

   ```
   private static Node addTwoNumbers(Node l1, Node l2) {
       if (l1 == null) {
           if (l2 == null) {
               return null;
           }
           return addTwoNumbers(l2, l1);
       }
       int add = l2 == null ? 0 : l2.data;
       if (l1.data + add > 9) {
           if (l1.next != null) {
               l1.next.data++;
           } else {
               l1.next = new Node(1);
           }
       }
       l1.data = (l1.data + add) % 10;
       l1.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2 == null ? null : l2.next);
       return l1;
   }
   ```